# I can not watch HD videos

Tags: gpu-driver

my name is Matthias.
I have a little "big" problem. I have a Packard Bell EasyNote TK 11 BZ with the Video Card AMD Radeon HD 6310 can but not a full HD watch videos with your driver, either on the computer or on Youtube. Thank you.
If the one who answers when he speaks German, I beg you to answer in German, this question is translated by Google Translator

Comment: Could you give more details?What do you mean it`s not working?

Comment: I have now found out that this can also be the Flash player, because what can not be true if flash games and Youtube plays slow?

Answer (score 0):

In my AMD chipset experience, you will need proprietary drivers and although you have not specified what version of Ubuntu you are running, I can direct you to AMD's driver downloads. The package I used can be found at http://support.amd.com/en-us/download/desktop?os=Linux+x86#amd-catalyst-packages and the newest beta driver is at http://support.amd.com/en-us/kb-articles/Pages/Latest-LINUX-Beta-Driver.aspx as well.
Each page lists the necessary requirements; especially make sure your kernel is supported and if you are running 64-bit then make sure 32-bit libraries are installed.
I would suggest choosing the first of the links as playing with betas is almost always a bad idea for the average user. Both list the Radeon HD 6000 series as supported. Either download should include a script to run, which opens either a graphical interface or will work in a terminal, I've done both install types successfully.